# Does `git diff` distinguish the part added into branch2 and the part removed from branch1?

Tags: git

When comparing the tip commits of two branches by `git diff branch_1..branch_2`,

- does the output distinguish the part added into branch2 and the part removed from branch1?
- does the output distinguish the part removed from branch2 and the part added  into branch1?

If not, is there some way to distinguish?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. `git diff` compares just two commits without caring if they are tips of branches or not.

Comment: Have you tried running it on an example and gotten something you didn't expect?

Comment: @Mad: yes. I didn't find the output distinguish what I asked.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really any notion of "removed from" or "added to" at this level (unlike `git merge`).  Git is merely comparing the two commits' files directly.

Given `git diff branch_1..branch_2`, Git first simply *removes* the `..`, leaving `git diff branch_1 branch_2`.  (This is different from almost every other Git command: the special treatment of `..` in `git diff` is exclusive to `git diff`.)  Now that there are just two branch names or other commit specifiers, Git translates them to tree hash IDs, as if with:

```
git rev-parse branch_1^{tree}
```

and:

```
git rev-parse branch_2^{tree}
```

By this point, all notion of "branching" is gone entirely: all Git has, and needs, is the two trees.  It then compares the two trees, finding files with the same names and/or contents (depending on flags such as `-M` and `-B`), and then does an individualized diff of each file-pair (unless that's suppressed, e.g., `--name-only` or `--name-status`).

Comment: Thanks. is there some way to distinguish?

Comment: @Tim: To know what has happened on two commits with respect to a third (earlier) commit, you must first identify the third commit! This is (part of) what `git merge` does: it locates the third commit, if there is one. There may be none, one, or more than one. You must decide what to do in each case. Then, having found the third commit, you need *two* `git diff`s, one from third (base) commit to each branch-tip commit. (This is the second part of what `git merge` does.)